# AngularJS - Select, set default values for Edit/New

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

First project working with AngularJS and I am a bit stuck using the select list to either set the default value to the first option for a new, or if its an edit select the value.

I have a form with two select lists. Note, I am thinking i'm wrong in my ng-options tag.

**invite.tpl.html**

```
<select ng-model="selectedUser" ng-options="user.id as user.user_name for user in users"></select>
<select ng-model="selectedEvent" ng-options="event.id as event.name for event in events"></select>
```

A controller that gets/posts JSON.

**invite.js**

```
.controller('InviteCtrl', function InviteController( $scope, InviteRes, $state, $stateParams ) {
  $scope.inviteId = parseInt($stateParams.inviteId, 10);
  $scope.users = InviteRes.Users.query();
  $scope.events = InviteRes.Events.query();

  //EDIT (HAVE ID) - SET SELECTS TO THE USER/EVENT 
  if ($scope.inviteId) {
    $scope.invite = InviteRes.Invites.get({id: $scope.inviteId});
    $scope.selectedUser = $scope.invite.user_id;
    $scope.selectedEvent = $scope.invite.event_id;
  }
  //NEW (NO ID) - SET DEFAULT OPTIONS TO FIRST USER/EVENT
  else {
    $scope.selectedUser = $scope.users[0];
    $scope.selectedEvent = $scope.events[0];
    $scope.invite = new InviteRes.Invites();
  }
```

Function to save.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.invite.user_id = $scope.selectedUser;
    $scope.invite.event_id = $scope.selectedEvent;
    //IF ID - UPDATE ELSE NEW
    if ($scope.inviteId) {
      $scope.invite.$update(function(response) {
        $state.transitionTo('invites');
      }, function(error) {
        $scope.error = error.data;
      });
    }
    else {
      $scope.invite.$save(function(response) {
        $state.transitionTo('invites');
      }, function(error) {
        $scope.error = error.data;
      });
    }
  };
```

And a getting those resources

```
.factory( 'InviteRes', function ( $resource )  {
  return {
    Invites: $resource("../invites/:id.json", {id:'@id'}, {'update': {method:'PUT'}, 'remove': {method: 'DELETE', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}}),
    Users: $resource('../users.json'),
    Events: $resource('../events.json'),
  };
})
```

I looked around and found some articles explaining how to do this, but everything I've tried has either given me issues with either setting the values, or saving the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource API doesn't return immediately - see the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) for the following statement:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference

Could it simply be that you're trying to assign the value before it's available?

Could you change your code to read something like:

```
if ($scope.inviteId) {
    $scope.invite = InviteRes.Invites.get({id: $scope.inviteId}, function() {
        $scope.selectedUser = $scope.invite.user_id;
        $scope.selectedEvent = $scope.invite.event_id;
    });
}
```

In terms of the select directive, I tend to use objects rather than values, e.g.

```
<select ng-model="selectedUser" ng-options="user.user_name for user in users"></select>
// in controller:
$scope.selectedUser = $scope.users[1];
```

Comment: Wow - thank you so much that fixed it - very good to know going forward!